# Entity Framework - Complex Type not required to be defined in Context

Tags: entity-framework-5

I was struggling with the complex type error while enabling the migrations in my App with the following error:

```
The type 'eCommerceDataModel.Models.UserImage' has already been configured as an entity type. 
It cannot be reconfigured as a complex type.
```

Just sharing this as you might face this silly issue.
When using Complex Type please don't define the complex type entity in Context Class.

```
public class eComContext : DbContext
{
    public eComContext() : base("eCommDB") { }
    public IDbSet<SiteSettings> SiteSettings { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    //public IDbSet<UserImage> UserImage { get; set; } (This needs to be removed)
}

[Table("SiteDetails")]
public class SiteSettings
{
    [Key]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30), MinLength(5)] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50), MinLength(10)] 
    public string PunchLine { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

[Table("SiteUsers")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public byte Password { get; set; }
    public UserImage UserImage { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class UserImage
{
    public byte[] PhotoSmall { get; set; }
    public byte[] PhotoMedium { get; set; }
    public byte[] PhotoLarge { get; set; }
}
```

The UserImage property in Context class needs to be remove to resolve this error. And now am able to enable the migrations.

Comment: You should move your answer into the answer section below.